# Como reconectar un websocket en android?

Tags: android, android-studio, websocket

Estoy desarrollando una `App` en `Android Studio` y estoy Intentando que mi `websocket` se re-conecte automáticamente en caso de que la conexión falle o el mismo se cierre, pero no encuentro de que forma hacerlo, espero puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré un método de re conexión de mi `websocket`, al momento en que se crea un cliente para una conexión en especifico, es importante saber que ese cliente, no puede reutilizarse al momento de hacer un intento de re conexión de `websocket`, a menos que:

```
if(mWebSocketClient!=null){
        mWebSocketClient.getConnection().close();
        mWebSocketClient=null;
    }
```

Tomemos nuestro cliente y lo hagamos nulo, de manera que al momento de reutilizarlo nos permita usar en este caso la misma variable para la re conexión que seria lo mas idóneo y organizado posible. Luego, sencillamente se restaura la conexión, de esta forma:

```
mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri)
```

Y implementando los respectivos métodos, `onOpen`, `onClose`, `onMessage`, `onError` y `onClosing` para lo que necesite la `app`.

Así resolví mi problema, espero a alguien mas le funcione.